# Скрипт добавления письма в Gmail через социальные закладки

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

Написал скрипт социальных закладок. Скрипт  не работает с html-режимом (упрощенным) Gmail. Есть пункт "Google Mail", на клике по которому открывается gmail с заполненными полями. Скрипт генерирует ссылку вида

> `http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&su=Porsche&body=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.porsche.com%2Farticles%2Fporsche-classic-restoration`
>
> Porsche - заголовок страницы
>
> `local.porsche.com%2Farticles%2Fporsche-classic-restoration` - урл страницы, которую добавляют

Проблема в том, что эта ссылка не работает с упрощенным режимом Gmail, если он установлен по умолчанию у пользователя, Гугл пишет 404 страница не найдена. Кто знает как можно переписать урл, чтоб она передавала нужные параметры.Чтоб скрипт работал и с упрощенным режимом и со стандартным?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю на аяксе подгрузить страницу, открываемую по этой ссылке, затем полученный контент сравнить с образцом оного в скрипте. Если данные аякса и данные образца не совпали, то переносим нашего пользователя на полную форму отправки. Думаю, так будет работать.

Скачиваешь на комп страницу с ошибкой 404.Какую то универсальную часть кода выбираешь(где контент 404-ой не меняется) и создаёшь в скрипте закладoк переменную,например:

```
var errorpage="404"
//думаю,надпись 404 там точно есть).
```

Это выражение оставить в теле скрипта навсегда.

Ещё добавить переменную-флаг:

```
flag=0;
//будет сигнализировать об ошибке 404.
```

Далее по клику на кнопку Gmail осуществлять аякс-запрос по такой схеме(я на jQuery делаю):

```
$.ajax({
url:"URL,куда ведёт кнопка",
dataType:"html",
success: function(data){
$(data).find(errorpage).each(function(){var flag=1});
//выполним проверку
if (flag==1){перешлём пользователя на полную форму гмайла,т.к. краткую форму он не любит}
else {перешлём пользователя на краткую форму гмайла,т.к. не выдаётся ошибка 404}
}
})
```

Comment: Честно говоря, что-то не очень понял суть идеи.

Comment: Спасибо за такое подробное объяснение, идея понравилась. Только остается решить последний основной вопрос: Как правильно сформировать урл с передаваемыми параметрами для простой формы gmail, ведь именно в этом месте и основная загвоздка. Все что не передаешь ей она выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

А для чего эти вот параметры в линке нужны?

```
.../?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1
```

мб их значения попробовать **поменять**?..мне вот симпатичен "view",что с английского переводится,как "вид,тип,опция".

Comment: Эти параметры нужны для того чтобы при открытии почты, сразу было создано новое письмо с заполненными полями заголовка и тела письма, пользователю остается только выбрать кому отправить и собственно нажать отправить. Без этих параметров никак.